# copying local files to hdfs is very very slow

Tags: hadoop, copy, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to copy local files to the hdfs using following command

> $ hdfs dfs -put [local_path] [dfs_uri]

the commands works and copy the files, but 2 KB/sec or even slower.

any help appreciated :)

NOTE: Cloudera Express 5.5.1 (#8 built by jenkins on 20151201-1818 git: 2a7dfe22d921bef89c7ee3c2981cb4c1dc43de7b)

Comment: Where are you running this command from? Cluster or PC?

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju
i am running this command using ssh connection in the hdfs master node, which also contain the files i need to copy to the hdfs.
The same problem exists with Hue, when upload a file it takes hours to uplaod. e.g: uploading 300MB file took me 8 hours :)

Comment: In that case, it could be the network issue. Probably working with your network admin might help. Typically, you should have gateway node in the same cluster which you should use to copy data to HDFS

Comment: i am using Ubuntu server 14.04, i have search google, someone purpose to change to CentOS. I don't know the problem is with OS, setting or something else